# Framework vs. Plug-in

Tags: xcode, plugins, frameworks

I have an app that draws shapes on the screen, I have another app that uses the same enviroment (frameworks) of the first app, but draws a special kind of shapes. I might write several apps that draw special shapes. What is the best way to link them to one app via Xcode?

Create each one as a framework? Or as a plug-in bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A framework is linked to your app code, whereas with a plug-in, you need to fetch function pointers.  The plug-in design would make sense if the plug-in, or some of its functions, might be missing.  But if each of the functions is required by each of your apps, using a framework would be simpler.